# Не выводятся данные о количестве общих записей в DataGrid и отображаемых записей после фильтров в TextBlock. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Предоставляю саму проблему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

C#:

```
private void Otobrazit_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int T = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox2.SelectedValue);
            Otobrazit.Text = $"Найдено - {ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities2.GetContext().Students.Where(x => x.ID_GroupStudent == T).ToList()}" +
                $" из {GD.ItemsSource = ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities2.GetContext().Students.ToList().Count().ToString()}";
        }
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="Otobrazit" IsVisibleChanged="Otobrazit_IsVisibleChanged" > Найдено (х) из (х)</TextBlock>
```

Если убрать код с выводом отображения фильтруемых записей, то вывод количества всех записей работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Поэтому прошу помощи как отобразить количество именно фильтруемых записей :(